# Can a KafkaConsumer read data from topic written by SourceTask?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

If we have written into a Kafka topic data using a SourceTask, in which we have defined a Schema for SourceRecords different than Schema.STRING_SCHEMA, that is a custom schema for example:

```
private final Schema valueSchema = SchemaBuilder.struct()
.field("dim0", Schema.FLOAT64_SCHEMA)
.field("dim1", Schema.FLOAT64_SCHEMA)
.field("dim2", Schema.FLOAT64_SCHEMA)
.field("dim3", Schema.FLOAT64_SCHEMA)
.build();
```

**then is it possible for a KafkaConsumer to be able to read data from that topic?**

Or only SinkTask can read data from that topic since you can define Schema for SinkRecords as you can for SourceRecords?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You would rely on the `Converter` interface to handle the serialization for you.

The method in the source code for this is [`fromConnectData`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/Converter.html#fromConnectData-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema-java.lang.Object-).

[image]

Ones I know of for `Struct` objects.

- `JsonConverter` is included with Apache Kafka
- `AvroConverter` is from Confluent
- `ProtobufConverter` is from BlueApron.

If you used `StringConveter`, you'd end up with records that look like `Struct{dim0=1,dim1=2,dim2=3,dim3=4}`, which would have to be manually parsed as compared to getting proper structured objects using the other options.

The Converters are often wrappers around `Serializer` and `Deserializer` interfaces, so you would include the corresponding `Deserializer` class in your consumer code.

img src: [Deep Dive](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained) blog from Confluent.

Comment: According to the documentation provided in the book: *Kafka: The Definitive Guide*: "When the connector returns a Data API record to the worker, the worker then uses the configured converter to convert the record to either an Avro object, JSON object, or a string, and the result is then stored into Kafka." I would like to ask if there is support for custom binary objects or only for those three kinds of object?

Comment: ByteArrayConverter exists. And, as I mentioned, there's one for Protobuf as well